# Dirichlet conditions being ignored

Tags: version-10, computational-geometry, differential-equations, finite-element-method

I have the following domain:

```
rA=ImplicitRegion[((x - 10)/0.2)^2 + y^2 <= 
   1 || ((x + 10)/0.2)^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}]
rB=ImplicitRegion[((x - 6)/0.2)^2 + (y + 20)^2 <= 
   1 || ((x + 6)/0.2)^2 + (y + 20)^2 <= 1, {x, y}]
Dom = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-100, -100}, {100, 100}], 
  RegionUnion[ rA , rB]]
```

Then try to solve Laplace equation on the domain, applying boundary conditions:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0,
   DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y] == 
     100, ((x - 10)/0.2)^2 + y^2 <= 1 || ((x + 10)/0.2)^2 + y^2 <= 
      1],
   DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y] == 
     0, ((x - 6)/0.2)^2 + (y + 20)^2 <= 
      1 || ((x + 6)/0.2)^2 + (y + 20)^2 <= 1],
   u[x, -100] == u[x, 100] == u[-100, y] == u[100, y] == 0}, u, 
  Element[{x, y}, Dom]]
```

But I get errors

```
NDSolveValue::bcnop: No places were found on the boundary where 25. (-10+x)^2+y^2<=1||25. (10+x)^2+y^2<=1 was True, so DirichletCondition[u==100,25. (-10+x)^2+y^2<=1||25. (10+x)^2+y^2<=1] will effectively be ignored. >>
NDSolveValue::bcnop: No places were found on the boundary where 25. (-6+x)^2+(20+y)^2<=1||25. (6+x)^2+(20+y)^2<=1 was True, so DirichletCondition[u==0,25. (-6+x)^2+(20+y)^2<=1||25. (6+x)^2+(20+y)^2<=1] will effectively be ignored. >>
```

I tried a more succinct semantics, but I get even more errors:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0,
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 100, 
    Element[{x, y}, RegionBoundary[rA]]],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, 
    Element[{x, y}, RegionBoundary[rB]]],
   u[x, -100] == u[x, 100] == u[-100, y] == u[100, y] == 0}, u, 
  Element[{x, y}, Dom]]



ImplicitRegion::ivar: "-100. is not a valid variable."
CompiledFunction::cfta: "Argument {{Boole[{-100.,-100.}\[Element]RegionBoundary[ImplicitRegion[LessEqual[<<2>>]||LessEqual[<<2>>],{-100.,-100.}]]]},{Boole[{-100.,-87.5}\[Element]RegionBoundary[ImplicitRegion[LessEqual[<<2>>]||LessEqual[<<2>>],{-100.,-87.5}]]]},<<47>>,{Boole[{87.5,-100.}\[Element]RegionBoundary[ImplicitRegion[LessEqual[<<2>>]||LessEqual[<<2>>],{87.5,-100.}]]]},<<78>>} at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor of \!\(\"machine-size integer\"\)s"
NDSolveValue::bcnop: "No places were found on the boundary where {x,y}\[Element]RegionBoundary[ImplicitRegion[25.\ Plus[<<2>>]^2+y^2<=1||25.\ Plus[<<2>>]^2+y^2<=1,{x,y}]] was True, so DirichletCondition[u==100,{x,y}\[Element]RegionBoundary[ImplicitRegion[25.\ Power[<<2>>]+y^2<=1||25.\ Power[<<2>>]+y^2<=1,{x,y}]]] will effectively be ignored"
....
```

Comment: Try using `Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
  "MeshOptions" -> {"BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"}}` does this help?

Answer (score 1):

This works in Version 10.2:

```
rA = ImplicitRegion[((x - 10)/0.2)^2 + y^2 <= 
    1 || ((x + 10)/0.2)^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}]
rB = ImplicitRegion[((x - 6)/0.2)^2 + (y + 20)^2 <= 
    1 || ((x + 6)/0.2)^2 + (y + 20)^2 <= 1, {x, y}]
Dom = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-100, -100}, {100, 100}], 
  RegionUnion[rA, rB]]
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y] == 
     100, ((x - 10)/0.2)^2 + y^2 <= 1 || ((x + 10)/0.2)^2 + y^2 <= 1],
    DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y] == 
     0, ((x - 6)/0.2)^2 + (y + 20)^2 <= 
      1 || ((x + 6)/0.2)^2 + (y + 20)^2 <= 1], 
   u[x, -100] == u[x, 100] == u[-100, y] == u[100, y] == 0}, u, 
  Element[{x, y}, Dom]]
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] sol["ElementMesh"], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Here are the seed points inside the region holes:

```
sol["ElementMesh"]["RegionHoles"]
{{10.016713574468996`, 
  0.059658883955950155`}, {-5.9832860016757525`, \
-19.940335393998154`}, {6.016708912061227`, -19.940335393998154`}, \
{-9.983289604445392`, 0.059661427087461485`}}
```